# Wifi disconnects 2.4Ghz at specific places, 5Ghz works fine

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, raspberry-pi, openwrt

I have a Tenda AC1200 AX10 router set up in AP mode, it is connected to a Raspberry Pi running OpenWRT, which is in turn connected to two ISP routers using TP-Link UE300 Ethernet to USB Adapter. The RPi is set up as the DHCP server. I have another RPi running the HomeAssistant OS and have multiple NodeMCUs for automation. Now, previously I didn't have this issue, but after the addition of the RPi OpenWRT, this bizarre Wi-Fi issue has started occurring.
My Wi-Fi is on the ground floor, now approx 10m from the router, the 2.4Ghz network starts dropping, there is good signal strength, yet either my device cannot connect to it, or if it does, it cannot access the locally hosted services like the HomeAssistant. I tried to verify this with my mobile, and both Android and iOS cannot connect at that place and on the terrace. It is strange, because just moving 1 or 2 feet away from that location starts working, even moving further away. I tried changing channels by scanning that area and trying to remove interference, but the problem still persists.
I have two neighbours adjacent to my house, and I have come to the conclusion after verifying this issue throughout the house, that it occurs only near the wall dividing our houses, also the signal strength of their Wi-Fi is greater than mine, but it's on a different channel.
What all I have tried already

1. Restarting the router
2. Different devices (none of them works)
3. Changing channels
4. Changing the bandwidth to 20, 40, 20/40
5. Removing the RPi OpenWRT and using the router in DHCP mode.

I had been trying to solve this for the past 10 days, but I can't think of a solution.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: if your issue is based on physical places and particular frequencies, and the signal is strong, you are almost certainly dealing with RF interference in your problematic band.

Comment: This interference is continuous, so I guess we can rule out home appliances that are not running 24/7, I don't have any devices that might cause this issue, maybe my neighbour does, but this issue is there even on the 2nd floor. Also, sometimes my NodeMCUs connect to Wi-Fi but cannot connect to my HomeAssistant.